# Can we send tuple directly to a bolt at specific supervisors Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a business case like this. We're developing a web crawling system. So there is some sites that need VPN to access. There are only certain servers which are installed VPN service. So I need to send the crawling URL job directly to Storm's worker on these servers so it can use VPN installed on these servers particularly.

Another case is sometimes we would navigate more jobs to a particular servers because of bigger resources or specific environment. So I have a couple of questions:

- If we have like 10 physical servers (supervisors), if we set Storm's number of workers to >= 10, does it guarantee that all supervisors have a worker of Topology? Because at first we need to make sure there is a worker installed on VPN server. Or we need custom scheduler for Storm?
- Is there any way to force sending tuples to specific supervisor? For ex: url abc.com needs VPN to access, server #10 has VPN, how to send this job to server #10? I guess I can use direct grouping but not sure about this, or use all grouping to send to all workers, but it is very expensive.

Thank u for reading. Hope you can help.